# Can someone tell me why this simple bit of c# code won't work, involves recursively calling method from within itself to get the root category ID

Tags: c#, .net, linq, entity-framework

All root categories in table have a PCATID of null.
The method actually does the job, sets cat to the very root
category, but then amazingly fails to return it once
it hits `return cat;` does some weird jumping in and
out of the "if" statement, then again to `GetRootCat(cat);`
and returns not the root category, but the first parent
category of cat.

Call:

```
listModel.PCATID = GetRootCat(cat).CategoryID;
```

Method:

```
    private Category GetRootCat(Category cat)
    {

        if (cat.PCATID != null)
        {
            cat = repository.Categories.FirstOrDefault(x => x.CategoryID == cat.PCATID);
            GetRootCat(cat);

        }

            return cat;
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Replace

```
GetRootCat(cat);
```

with

```
return GetRootCat(cat);
```

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't "fail to return", it returns to itself because it's a recursive call. But when it calls itself, it throws away the return value, and falls through to the `return cat`, which gives you the parent of the category you called it with.

This would be more sane:

```
private Category GetRootCat(Category cat) {
    if (cat.PCATID == null) { /* This is the root */
      return cat;
    } else {
        Category parent = repository.Categories.FirstOrDefault(x => x.CategoryID == cat.PCATID);
        return GetRootCat(parent);
    }
}
```

Comment: It still works fine as long as I just use return GetRootCat(cat);